# Android: [Firebase] Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it

Tags: android, firebase

I got error related to CursorWindow as logged below.
As you see the log, the IllegalStateException is caused by Firebase SDK.
So, I updated the latest SDK version (com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.1.1), but it still happened.
I don't know exactly when this is happened, because I just check the issue from the firebase console.
So, I'm finding out which use-case cause the exception below.

One clue is that this is occured since I've refactored all code to AndroidX library by AndroidStudio.

If you have the same experience as me, and you've solved this problem, please help me out.

Thank you in advance.

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 7934, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
       at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(CursorWindow.java)
       at android.database.CursorWindow.getString + 438(CursorWindow.java:438)
       at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString + 51(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLiteLruReferenceDelegate.lambda$removeOrphanedDocuments$2 + 157(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:157)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLiteLruReferenceDelegate$$Lambda$3.accept + 6(:6)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLitePersistence$Query.forEach + 485(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:485)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLiteLruReferenceDelegate.removeOrphanedDocuments + 155(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:155)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LruGarbageCollector.removeOrphanedDocuments + 226(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:226)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LruGarbageCollector.runGarbageCollection + 270(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:270)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LruGarbageCollector.collect + 245(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:245)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalStore.lambda$collectGarbage$9 + 670(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:670)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalStore$$Lambda$10.get + 4(:4)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLitePersistence.runTransaction + 229(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:229)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalStore.collectGarbage + 670(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:670)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LruGarbageCollector$Scheduler.lambda$scheduleGC$0 + 144(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:144)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LruGarbageCollector$Scheduler$$Lambda$1.run + 2(:2)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$DelayedTask.handleDelayElapsed + 134(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:134)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$DelayedTask.access$lambda$0()
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$DelayedTask$$Lambda$1.run + 2(:2)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call + 457(Executors.java:457)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run + 266(FutureTask.java:266)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run + 301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker + 1162(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run + 636(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$DelayedStartFactory.run + 224(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.1.1:224)
       at java.lang.Thread.run + 764(Thread.java:764)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cursor, make sure that to get columns or data your method should be cursor.moveToFirst() and yes, make sure also cursor should be initialize or not.

Comment: I think it's not such an error. It's related to Firebase SDK as log show us. Of course, I do not use any cursor, firebase did I guess.